# http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ Css bug in questions with more than 1000 views

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

In https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ I was looking the question list. In question list, the views are like 39, and below it is 'views' written over there. But in questions with more than 1000 views, let's say 3669 views, it should show 4k and below it 'views'. But the way shown becomes 4 and at bottom 'kviews'. I don't know if it's a bug or done like that knowingly, but I guess it's a bug.

It's a bug report, not a question. The question anyway may be that is that way is done knowingly?

Example: Look at this question in question list: Can I make the Google Hangout window full screen?

Comment: I imagine it would cause formatting issues if the "k" was placed next to a 2 or especially a 3 digit number (given the large font size).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi-I knew what's kviews, but I hope that's bug.

Comment: @TimMedora-3 digit numbers can be placed there, and so 2 digits+k can also be placed. For 3 digit + k, there is m-for million.

Comment: @k_programmer, that's not a bug as far as I can tell, more like a language quirk (a cute one if you ask me).